# SQL ordering behaviour by multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sorting, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

Assume we have the following **People** table:

```
  Name  | Id  | Employee type
-------------------------------
  Max   | 2   | Engineer
  Alice | 3   | Scientist
  Bob   | 1   | Scientist
  John  | 4   | Engineer
  Jane  | 5   | Engineer
```

and now we want to order them as follows: First, we have the Scientists, then the Engineers. The scientists should be ordered by **name in ascending order** and the engineers by **id in descending order**.

Hence, the result should be

```
  Name  | Id  | Employee type
-------------------------------
  Alice | 3   | Scientist
  Bob   | 1   | Scientist
  Jane  | 5   | Engineer
  John  | 4   | Engineer
  Max   | 2   | Engineer
```

Of course, I could first run a query for the Engineers and then another one for the Scientists. However, I am wondering whether there is another more elegant solution.

My question is now, how can we achieve that we an elegant query? Ideally, you can formulate is as a sqlalchemy query, but a simple SQL statement would also help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two `case`-statements in the `order by` clause:

```sql
select p.* from people p order by p.employee_type desc, 
      case when p.employee_type = 'Scientist' then p.name else '' end asc,
      case when p.employee_type = 'Engineer' then p.id else '' end desc
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1m4NSX3T)

Comment: many thanks for your input. Could you help me in formulating it into an SQL query?

Comment: Also, how would the query change in case the ID was a string and we would like to that?

Comment: @tobias what would those string IDs look like?

Comment: just some random srings like "abcd" and "bcde".

Comment: It would be terrific if one could write ascending and descending into the case part. Is that possible? I tried that, but it just returned some errors.

Comment: @tobias Please see my recent edit

Comment: Is there some way to write this down in sqlalchemy?